# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

me tira el siguiente error en la linea 43, linea 43 es donde coloco el i=0, lo que necesito en esa parte es acomodar por numero de ordenes de mayor a menor, pasando por todas las mesas, intente haciendo un ciclo pero no me funciono me salio (TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
###Ingreso la cantidad de ordenes que quiero, tienen que ser mayor a 4, menor a 10
cantidadOrdenes = int(input("-> CANTIDAD DE ORDENES PARA PROCESAMIENTO 
(ENTER): "))
while cantidadOrdenes>10 or cantidadOrdenes<4:
print("** ERROR: DEBE INGRESAR UNA CANTIDAD DE ORDENES MAYOR A 4 PERO MENOR 10 ** ")
print(f"USUARIO INGRESO: {cantidadOrdenes} ")###Aqui muestra lo que digito el usuario, para que no se vuelva a equivocar, le dice que tiene que ser un numero mayor a 4 pero menor a 10
cantidadOrdenes = int(input("-> CANTIDAD DE ORDENES PARA PROCESAMIENTO (ENTER): "))
#####Si el Usuario digito mal muestra el mensaje de arriba

###contadorOrden, esta variable de contador lo que va hacer es que cada vuelta le sume a la orden y aparezca por cual vuelta voy
contadorOrden=0
####Aqui acomode las mesas del restaurante del 0-14
####el 0 es la posición de la mesa, el otro 0 posicion orden
listaMesas = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0], 
[10,0],[11,0],[12,0],[13,0],[14,0]]
indexMesas = 0 ###el numero de mesa es la posición 0
indexOrdenes = 1 ###el numero de orden es la posición 1
print("->INSTRUCCIONES: Ingrese para cada número de orden el número de mesa 
(ENTER). ")
###le decimos al usuario que para cada orden que ingreso arriba, ponga el 
número de mesa
for contadorOrden in range(0,cantidadOrdenes):
###este contador lo utilice para ir viendo por cual orden voy, y no perdeme con las ordenes que digito, mejor dicho  verificar que funcione bien
numeroMesa = int(input(f"# ORDEN : {contadorOrden} "))
listaMesas [numeroMesa][indexOrdenes] += 1
####esta no estaba entre las que menciono el profe, pero siento que es necesaria, hay cada persona que puede digitar un -1 o 15 o x numero
###con este ciclo le volvemos a preguntar al usuario
while numeroMesa<0 or numeroMesa>14:
    print("** ERROR: NO TENEMOS TANTAS MESAS EN NUESTRO RESTAURANTE. NUESTRAS MESAS VAN DESDE LA 0-14 ** ")
    print(f"USUARIO INGRESO: {numeroMesa} ")### le mostramos al usuario lo que ingreso y le notificamos el rango de números que puede utilizar
    ####Si el usuario digita mas mesas de las que hay, sale lo de arriba
    numeroMesa = int(input("->INSTRUCCIONES: Ingrese para cada número de orden el número de mesa (ENTER). "))
    ####Volvemos a preguntar
    contadorOrden += 1###si no, utilizo este contador, me cuenta infinitamente
i=0
print("** REPORTE: FRECUENCIA DE MESAS (Mayor a menor frecuencia)**: ")
for i in listaMesas:
####Mesa mas frecuente, esto es acorde a lo que ingresa el usuario arriba
    mesaMayorOrden = listaMesas[0] ###mesaMayor es igual al indice 0 de la 
lista de mesas de ahi comenzaremos.
    for numeroMesa in listaMesas: ###Recordemos que nuestro numeroMesa es 
donde ingresamos los datos del usuario, y estos los guardamos en listaMesas.
        if numeroMesa[indexOrdenes] > mesaMayorOrden[indexOrdenes]:
            mesaMayorOrden = numeroMesa
            print(f"MESA: {mesaMayorOrden[indexMesas]} , 
{mesaMayorOrden[indexOrdenes]} ")###Imprimimos todas nuestras mesas, con los 
valores ingresados por el usuario.
```

Comment: Pues a mi no me da ese error. Por que declaras e inicializas la variable i=0? Luego no hace uso de ella.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el for que haces que no tiene ningún sentido. Un entero no es iterable y es lo que estás tratando de hacer.

Prueba a cambiar ese for por:

```
for i in range(len(listaMesas)):
```

De esta forma i en cada iteración valdrá un entero (desde 0 hasta el tamaño de la lista).

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes una posible solucion. Aunque no observo el error que mencionabas, tu codigo tenia algunos problemas. Si no entiendes algo de los pequeños cambios que realice puedes dejarme un comentario.

```
# Ingreso la cantidad de ordenes que quiero, tienen que ser mayor a 4, menor a 10
cantidadOrdenes = int(input("-> CANTIDAD DE ORDENES PARA PROCESAMIENTO (ENTER): "))

while cantidadOrdenes > 10 or cantidadOrdenes < 4:
    print("** ERROR: DEBE INGRESAR UNA CANTIDAD DE ORDENES MAYOR A 4 PERO MENOR 10 ** ")
    print(f"USUARIO INGRESO: {cantidadOrdenes} ")
    cantidadOrdenes = int(input("-> CANTIDAD DE ORDENES PARA PROCESAMIENTO (ENTER): "))

# ContadorOrden, esta variable de contador lo que va hacer es que cada vuelta
# le sume a la orden y aparezca por cual vuelta voy
contadorOrden=0
# Aqui acomode las mesas del restaurante del 0-14
# el primer numero es la mesa y el segundo es la cantidad de ordenes de esa mesa
listaMesas = [[0,0],
              [1,0],
              [2,0],
              [3,0],
              [4,0],
              [5,0],
              [6,0],
              [7,0],
              [8,0],
              [9,0],
              [10,0],
              [11,0],
              [12,0],
              [13,0],
              [14,0]]
indexMesas = 0 ###el numero de mesa es la posición 0
indexOrdenes = 1 ###el numero de orden es la posición 1
print("->INSTRUCCIONES: Ingrese para cada número de orden el número de mesa (ENTER). ")
###le decimos al usuario que para cada orden que ingreso arriba, ponga el 
###número de mesa
for contadorOrden in range(0,cantidadOrdenes):
# Este contador lo utilice para ir viendo por cual orden voy, y no perdeme con
# las ordenes que digito, mejor dicho  verificar que funcione bien
    while True:
        numeroMesa = int(input(f"# ORDEN : {contadorOrden} "))
        try:
            listaMesas[numeroMesa][indexOrdenes] += 1
            break
        except IndexError:
            print("** ERROR: NO TENEMOS TANTAS MESAS EN NUESTRO RESTAURANTE. NUESTRAS MESAS VAN DESDE LA 0-14 ** ")

# Aqui ordenaremos las mesas por frecuencia de ordenes en una nueva lista.
# Para esto usamos el metodo de la burbuja

listaMesasOrdenadas = listaMesas.copy()

for i in range(len(listaMesas) - 1):
    for j in range(len(listaMesas) - 1):
        if listaMesasOrdenadas[j][indexOrdenes] < listaMesasOrdenadas[j + 1][indexOrdenes]:
            listaMesasOrdenadas[j], listaMesasOrdenadas[j + 1] = listaMesasOrdenadas[j + 1], listaMesasOrdenadas[j]

print("** REPORTE: FRECUENCIA DE MESAS (Mayor a menor frecuencia)**: ")
for mesa in listaMesasOrdenadas:
    print(f"MESA: {mesa[indexMesas]} , {mesa[indexOrdenes]} ")
```